# Windows 7 - Network slow to wake up

Tags: windows-7, networking, motherboard

This is a pc running windows 7...

ISP: Comcast Cable

Router: Linksys WRT54G (running tomato)

Processor: intel i7 (i7-860)

Motherboard:  Asus P7P55D EVO

The motherboard has two nics on it. (not sure if this is relative)

At first .. any time the computer would come out from sleep ... it would take a good 5 minutes before i could hit google in any browser.

I turned the power saver off... and anytime i step away for a period of time... when i come to sit back down.. it takes about 5 mins before i can hit google in a browser. (says page cannot be display... i keep hitting f5 ... until it comes up)

ipconfig is always fully propogated with an ip and information.

The linux machine directly next to it never loses connection at all.. and can open a web page always instantly... so it is somethign WIN7 or motherboard/bios related. (my guess)

Has anyone ever heard of such an odd behavior from win7?  any suggestions for which way to go.  i tried googling several phrases but couldnt come up with anything substantial.

Does the bios make the network go to sleep when idle?

thanks and apologies for being long winded.

EDIT: So interestingly enough my ps3, and windows laptop is behaving the same.  therefor ruling out motherboard issue.  linux is not having any problems however. (interesting)

i guess i will attempt to find a replacement router next.

Comment: comcast dns issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if you have also turned off the power saver for you Ethernet or wireless adapters also as win 7 will turn off these in powersaver mode.
Go to your Ethernet or wireless adapter settings, configure, power management and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was extremely uneventful... but a very complicated explanation.

in the simplest form....

on the network i had a linksys wrt54g router flashed with tomato firmware... it was setup as a wireless ethernet bridge so i could plug in my xbox360 wired connection.

as soon as i unpluged the power on this router... everything else began acting correctly.

**in short - problem caused by user error - damn**